# Why doesn't AngularJS ng-click directive work inside generated search results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, algolia

I have defined a simple `ng-click` directive that happens to be inside of generated search results, but this directive doesn't work and I don't know why.

My app uses a **index.html** file in which AngularJS is bootstrapped and in which a controller is defined:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<main>
...
@@include('partials/search-results.html', {"title": "Results", "classTitle": "title_tablet-centered title_results" })
</main>
@@include('partials/footer.html')
</body>
</html>
```

The generated search results appear where the partial `@@include /partials/search-results.html` has been included. I don't have a view (e.g., via `<div ui-view>`) explicitly defined in `index.html`.

I'm using Algolia instantsearch for search, so within **search.js** I use an Algolia **hits** widget to display the list of results according to this template:

```
hitTemplate =
'<li class="hit">' +
'<div>
'<h5>{{{name}}}</h5>' +
'<p>{{{description}}}</p>' +
'<a href="#" ng-click="showDetails()">Read More</a>' + '</div>' +
'</li>';
```

The widget adds the `ng-click="showDetails()"` directive to the "Read More" button in each hit.

**MainCntrl.js**

```
(function() {
  function MainCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.showDetails = function(){
        console.log("Button clicked");
    };

  }
  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', MainCtrl]);
})();
```

**Behavior:** When I click on the "Read More" button in any of the search results, not only is no message logged to the console, but the search results get cleared and no error message appears in the console.

**Question:** Given that the search-results partial (and `showDetails()` directive) seem to be within the scope of ng-app, why doesn't the `ng-click` directive work?

Comment: Sounds like new items are never compiled after they appended to DOM.

Comment: @dfsq Do you mean compiled by Angular?

Comment: Yes, by Angular.

Comment: @dfsq. Ok, I guess I might try to manually `$compile` these DOM elements somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the new DOM generated element are not $compiled. Angular needs to know about those new DOM element created to be included in the $digest cycle. You need to manually $compile your template once generated.
You could directly get the wrapping div and compile the innerHTML once the search is done

What do you think ?

Comment: Thanks - a question... "You could directly get the wrapping div and compile the innerHTML once the search is done". On the surface, this sounds simple, but is it necessary to use a directive in conjunction with `$compile`?